# Ignore errors while loading to Mysql from Pyspark

Tags: mysql, pyspark

In redshift we can have maxerror Option

```
 df.write.option("url", jdbc_url) \
            .option("dbtable", tbl) \
            .option("tempdir", tmp_folder_rs) \
            .option("aws_iam_role", rs_iam) \
            .option("extracopyoptions", "**maxerror as 100000** blanksasnull") \
            .mode("append") \
            .save()
```

which gives it a tolerance of some records while loading.

Do we have similar options for MYSQL. My write to mysql is as below

```
job_status_event_req_cols.write.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://test.us-west-1.vpce.amazonaws.com/test").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "employee").option("user", "writer").option("password", "test").mode('append').save()
```